# Unable to grab api key from process.env in React Component

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect

I'm trying to pass the api key to the axios function from the process.env file, but i'm getting a type error of "cannot read properties of null (reading 0)". When I pass the "APIKEY" variable a string inside the component, it works great. Can anyone clarify what's happening, and how to make this work?

Thanks very much

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const APIKEY = process.env.REACT_APP_IMDB_API_KEY;
  // on page load, fetch api data
  useEffect(() => {
    const response = async () => {
      await axios
        .get(`https://imdb-api.com/en/API/SearchMovie/${APIKEY}/Spiderman%2020`)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data.results[0].image);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    };
    response();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>App</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Verify that your .env file is called just like that ".env", not "process.env" and that is located in the root directory of your app (not in src folder). REACT_APP_IMDB_API_KEY must equal the API key without quotation marks.

Comment: The file is called .env.local, and is located within the src folder, and inside is an input called "REACT_APP_IMDB_API_KEY=<key>"

Comment: It doesn't have to be inside src folder but in root directory. This means, right next to .src folder

Comment: My mistake, it is actually outside the src folder

Comment: You must also remove quotation marks from the .env file

Comment: There is no quotation marks within the .env.local file

Comment: Please add all the content of the .env file to the question. Ommiting the apy key, of course

Comment: The .env.local file shows: <REACT_APP_IMDB_API_KEY=apikey> without the brackets

Comment: If you can, copy the .env.local file address here. (You can right click and press copy relative path or something like that)

Comment: Right click relative path copy = .env.local

Comment: What if instead of defining APIKEY first, you just write process.env.REACT_APP_IMDB_API_KEY inside the braces in the axios call?

Comment: I get the same error when I run process.env inside the axios.get

Comment: Something I noticed, the value for the API key inside the .env file contains an underscore. For example, the value is k_03fh3fj. Will this cause issues?